# Why can't I have these two overloads in a class?

Tags: c++

In the code below, if I comment out `aaa` or `bbb` it will compile. Why can't I have both?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    typedef void (MyClass::*aaa)() const;
    typedef void (MyClass::*bbb)() const;
    void ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons() const {}
public:
    operator aaa() const { return (true) ? &MyClass::ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons : 0; }
    operator bbb() const { return (true) ? &MyClass::ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons : 0; }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass a;
    MyClass b;

    if(a && b) {}
}
```

Comment: @Wajih:  The class is not polymorphic (it has no virtual member functions), ergo there should be no vtable at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your typedefs for `aaa` and `bbb` are identical.  So your conversion operators are actually declaring the same function.

Essentially, the compiler sees

```
operator void (MyClass::*)() const { ... }
```

twice, once for `aaa`, and once for `bbb`.

Comment: To put it another way:  contrary to what the keyword `typedef` says, a `typedef` in C++ doesn't really _define_ a new type, it just creates an alias for an existing type.

Answer (score 1):

Because both are type defining the same type with a different name.

`aaa` is a pointer to a member function of `MyClass` that doesn't take any parameters and return a `void`.

`bbb` is also the same thing.